# What does the window.onerror colno parameter represent?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, specifications

I need precision regarding the expected `colno` value of window.onerror.

The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-errorevent-colno) says:

> The colno attribute must return the value it was initialized to. It represents the column number where the error occurred in the script.

*The position the error occurred in the script* is not clear to me. In the case of an undefined reference error for example, is it:

a) the start of the problematic reference or 
b) the end of it, since the error is when trying to use an invalid reference ?

Refer to the code below.

```js
window.onerror = function (message, filename, lineno, colno, error) {
console.log(colno);
}
// generate an "Uncaught ReferenceError"
generate.error;
```

The following recent browsers return 1 as the colno for the sample above.

- Firefox 51.0.1
- Chromium 53.0.2785.143
- Opera 43.0.2442.806

This would make me believe a) is right. However, as stated above, I find the spec ambiguous on this. In my mind, returning 9 (the position where the undefined `generate` ends) would also be valid. I would like some kind of authority on this matter.

What is the expected value of where an error occurred in JavaScript?

Comment: From my experience, error reporters usually point to the start of the token that somehow generates an error.

Comment: Yes, that's my experience too. I want to know if it's actually specified anywhere.